# Logitech PS2 Eye Toy on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, logitech-webcam

I recently pulled out my old PS2 Eye Toy (Black/Logitech) and attempted to get it working on my Windows 7 x64 PC. However, the driver I downloaded (I tried more than one), didn't work, and many comments on the downloads said it didn't work with 64 bit. Is there any way to get it working? Oddly, I can get the microphone to work without any drivers, although the sound is extremely off pitch, but no video.

Comment: http://metricrat.co.uk/ps2-eyetoy-on-windows-8-64-bit-working/ tried this?